# Eonasdan Datetimepicker with Ajax and Modal Pop Up

Tags: jquery, ajax, volt, eonasdan-datetimepicker

Datetimepicker bellow the modals on Ajax..

Datetimepicker can show if i dont use Ajax, here is the picture without ajax (in Modals) :
[image]

But it will show from the bellow of Modal if i use Ajax : 
[image]

I was use `$(document).ready()` with `css.('z-index',99999)`
And another approach but doesnt work.

Here is my full code :

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#pdstDateDeliver').datetimepicker({
            pickTime: false,
            format: 'DD/MM/YYYY',
            minDate: '{{ date("d/m/Y") }}'
        });
        $("#pdstDateDeliver").css('z-index', 999999); 
    });
</script>
```

This is call by Ajax

Comment: your question is hard to follow, can you provide a jsfiddle?

Answer (score -1):

i fixed it from the js library.
by added z-index to :

```
        return (
            '<div class="bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget dropdown-menu" style="z-index: 9999999 !important;">' +
                '<div class="datepicker">' + template + '</div>' +
            '</div>'
        );
```